# Why wrong in logic bigger than JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have error in my code, this code is operator logic in jquert, but it error:

when i put value **dipinjam = 2** & **tersedia = 10** result is TRUE, why like this?

```
var dipinjam = this.value;
var tersedia = $("#tersedia").val();
var sisa = tersedia - dipinjam;

if(dipinjam > tersedia){
     alert("Jumlah barang yang dipinjam melebihi barang tersedia");
}else{
     $("#sisa").val(sisa);
}
```

Comment: because "2" > "10" - just check `sisa < 0` - or `+dipinjum > +tersedia`

Comment: Convert your values into integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
if(Number(dipinjam) > Number(tersedia)){
     alert("Jumlah barang yang dipinjam melebihi barang tersedia");
}else{
     $("#sisa").val(sisa);
}
```

You should compare numbers, not strings

Comment: OP asks "why like this" - you've given a solution without explanation :p